# Get Modem Info in .Net Compact Framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, serial-port, modem

I am using .Net Compact Framework on a Windows Mobile 6 environment and I need to get a list of modems and the serial port that they're attached to.  In the full .Net Framework it can be easily done using System.Management.ManagementObject class; but, unfortunately this is not available in .NET Compact Framework and I haven't found any other way to do it. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually such info can be found in the registry. I'm not sure which keys exactly would contain the information you require, but a quick look showed me that \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ExtModems lists some modems on my WM6 device and each of them has a Port value.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but I've hit another brick wall of not having a driver for the modem that I can put on the mobile device.  I will certainly respond with success or failure of this method once I have been able to test it.